# Confirm "are you sure you want to leave this page" dialog with keyboard

Tags: macos, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

In Firefox, sometimes trying to navigate away from a website produces the following dialog:

[image: This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved.]

How do I select "Leave Page" using only my keyboard? I've tried pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select the "Leave Page" button, but instead it selects the URL bar, so I can't press <kbd>Enter</kbd>to press the button.

Comment: Try right-arrow: it works on Linux and Windows.

Comment: This seems to confirm from typing *any* character, destroying my work.  I want a way to NOT trigger this dialog unless I click it with a mouse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this on Firefox 51 on macOS 10.12, with [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onbeforeunload).

When the alert appears, press <kbd>Escape</kbd> to stay on the page, or press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to leave it. No need to try selecting the buttons with the arrow keys.

Comment: I somehow never tried this because I thought the "stay on page" button was selected, not the "leave page" button. Thanks!